# css issue: circle appears in a different position in Firefox than in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I'll apologize in advance... i'm not a css expert.  I'm having a problem where I'm drawing a circle beside a button.  The circle appears correctly in IE, but in Firefox, its too high.

I have the following css classes defined:

```
.circle {
    width:1.2em;
    height:1.2em;
    border-radius:50%;
    font-size:2em;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:1.2em; /* must match the height */
    text-align:center;
    background:#2b5f77;

    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top:239px;
    left: 340px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.circle:hover {
   border-top-color: #28597a;
   background: #28597a;
   color:#ec9226;
   }
.circle:active {
   border-top-color: #1b435e;
   background: #4d8eAE;

 }
```

And then the code to render the circle:

```
<div class="circle" value="i">i</div>
```

How change I change this code so that the circle appears in the same spot in all browsers?

**EDIT 1**

I'm testing with IE 9 standards mode.
and if it matters, the opening html tags look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
```

Thanks.

Comment: Need more information.
What are some of the other elements on the page surrounding it? Which versions of IE have you tested against other browsers?

I created http://jsfiddle.net/9zXLx/ and it appeared in the same spot in both IE 10 and Firefox.  So please give us additional information.

Comment: Please specify the IE version(s) you're testing. Also, check the rendering mode that IE is using -- confirm that it's not using compatibility mode or quirks mode.

Comment: I've updated my post.  please see Edit 1

Comment: Post some screenshots. `Its too high` is too vague.

Comment: Screenshots would be a HUGE help here - because from what I can tell (the link I posted earlier) it's in the same spot regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my testing, it seems if you remove these rules for your `.circle` css,

```
.circle {
    position: absolute;
    top:239px;
    left: 340px;
    }
```

and replace them with

```
.circle {
    position: relative;
    margin: 239px 0px 0px 340px;
    }
```

, you get the desired results. Tested and compared in Internet Explorer (9&10), Google Chrome & FF.

I'm not sure as to what is the exact cause for this, but the browser-specific body & html padding/ margin does play a small part.

Comment: i don't understand why it made a difference but that seems to fix the issue!  thanks.

Comment: to be more specific, your code helped to put the circle in the same spot in both browsers.  But i had to add a div that wraps both the button and the circle.. and set the top position for them to align properly.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to add a div around both the button and the cirle. and then force the positions like so:

```
.shared
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}
.buttonalign {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top:255px;
}

.circlealign {
    position: absolute;
    top:255px;
}
```

Here's the code that creates / modifies the html:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".submit").addClass("buttonalign");
        $('<div class="shared">').insertBefore($('.submit'));
          $('.submit').after($('<div class="circle circlealign" value="i">i</div></div>'));
    });
```

Thanks.